# reveal.js #+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag - list alignment

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode, reveal.js

I have a strange problem when exporting org-mode presentations to HTML via reveal.js:

- Topic

  ## +ATTR_REVEAL: :frag appear
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

aligns the bullet points correct (left)

but if I want to show the items one by one:

- Topic

  ## +ATTR_REVEAL: :frag appear
- Item 1

## +ATTR_REVEAL: :frag appear

- Item 2

## +ATTR_REVEAL: :frag appear

- Item 3

they get mixed up like this:

- Item 1 * Item 2

  - Item 3

this happens also with "frag roll-in", "frag grow", etc.

when looking into the HTML file, I find no differences

has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

## +ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (appear appear appear...)

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @muteaudio's answer, here is what the “lists can / be fragmented” § [should](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/pull/487) look like in the [documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hexmode/ox-reveal/master/Readme.org):

```
#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in roll-in)
    - Lists can
    - be fragmented.
```